# Overflowing a list horizontally

Tags: css

So I have an unordered list where I'm trying to have the li's overflow horizontally, but whenever they hit the boundary they just go below on a newline. Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: can you show your code for understand better what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space` property with `display:inline-block` like this:

```
ul {
 white-space:nowrap;
}
li {
 display:inline-block
 *display:inline;/* IE7 */
 *zoom:1;
 white-space:normal;
}
```